# Invoke-WebRequest - issue with special characters in json

Tags: powershell, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to send special characters (norwegian) using Invoke-WebRequest to an ASP .NET MVC4 API controller.

My problem is that the json object show up as NULL when received by the controller, if my json data contains characters like Æ Ø Å.

An example of my code:

```
$text = 'Æ Ø Å'
$jsondata = $text | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Uri http://contoso.com/create -ContentType 'application/json; charset=utf8' -Body $jsondata
```

Also when looking in fiddler the characters turn up like the usual weird utf8 boxes.

Sending json data from fiddler to the same API controller works fine

Any advice?

Comment: Can you try and fire up Fiddler to narrow down the problem?

Comment: `POST http://localhost:51212/api/Add HTTP/1.1
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 6.1; nb-NO) WindowsPowerShell/3.0
 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
 Host: localhost:51212
 Content-Length: 3
  
 ��� `

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For the `Body` parameter try this:

```
... -Body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($jsondata))
```

The string in PowerShell is Unicode but you've specified a UTF8 encoding so I think you need to give it some help getting to UTF8.

Comment: Thank you, I was in the misbelief of thinking that the string already was UTF8 since the ps file is UTF8.

Comment: @Keith Hill, this answer just totally saved me when I hit a similar issue and prevented a lot of pain. I wouldn't have thought the issue was Unicode -> UTF8. +1

Comment: This did not work for me. It results in one number per line and is obviously refused as JSON payload

Comment: December 2020 and still relevant! You just saved me from re-writing a whole script in another language ..

Comment: Still relevant in August 2022 as well! A few special characters were causing part of my scripts to fail suddenly, this has saved my bacon.

Comment: But why powershell do not do it by default !?! Thank you so much...

Comment: Still relevant in 2023 :-D