# How to encode german chars (like ü) with powershell for REST API?

Tags: rest, powershell

I'm creating users from PowerShell scripts by POSTing data collected from AD to a REST API enabled web portal, using:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

where $body is a JSON formatted propper payload, like this:

```
{
"email" : "klaus.mueller@domain.com",
"firstname" : "Klaus",
"lastname" : "Müller",
"active" : "true",
"superadmin" : "false"
}
```

If there is no german letter in name, all is O.K. and user is created. When there is a german character, I get 400 : Bad Request response from server.

Can I somehow change the behaviour of Invoke-RestMethod with setting encoding or its the server maybe configured not to receive de characters?

Comment: Try with `-Body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($body))` See [this technet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/726ecbbf-3a65-4385-b520-eae93fd7e3e9/converttojson-cmdlet-is-not-working-with-other-language-characters-like-etcneed?forum=winserverpowershell)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks @LoltPings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is similar to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290185/invoke-webrequest-issue-with-special-characters-in-json)

As @Keith Hill stated

> The string in PowerShell is Unicode but you've specified a UTF8 encoding so I think you need to give it some help getting to UTF8.

While the linked thread refers to Invoke-WebRequest, the encoding should still be valid for Invoke-RestMethod.

Your request should look something like this

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($body))
```