# How to use non-ASCII characters in Powershell script

Tags: powershell, non-ascii-characters

My powershell script needs to accept parameters with non-ASCII characters. And post it as Json to a API, but Powershell is converting all non-ASCII characters. How can I use the non-ASCII characters?

```
function Add-TestUser ([String] $name) {
   $body = @{name = $name}
   $JsonBody = $body | ConvertTo-Json
   write-host $name
   write-host $JsonBody
   #logic to call api
}

$name = "Caissière"
write-host $name

Add-TestUser -name $name
```

Output:

```
CaissiÃ¨re
CaissiÃ¨re
{
    "name":  "CaissiÃ¨re"
}
```

NOTE: script is run on a Windows Server

Comment: Don't use utf8 no bom encoding for the script.

Comment: Since the problem occurs with _string literals_ in your _source code_, the likeliest explanation is that your script file is misinterpreted by the Windows PowerShell engine, which happens if the script is saved as UTF-8 _without a BOM_. Try saving your script as UTF-8 _with BOM_. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: Thx for the direction to the answer. Never knew I could save the script with a different encoding. This helps.

It did lead me to a new error. The JsonBody is now containing the non-ASCII character, but this results in a api error: Request parameter type error: JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x72

Seems ConvertTo-Json needs a little help, as explained in: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290185/invoke-webrequest-issue-with-special-characters-in-json